# What is the event type of Input element in material-ui v1?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I'm using material-ui v1 and I'm struggling to find the event type for input elements. Considering the code snippet below:

```
<Select value={this.numberOfTickets} onChange={this.setNumberOfTickets}>
....
```

And the following `setNumberOfTickets` implementation:

```
@autobind @action
setNumberOfTickets(event: React.SyntheticEvent<HTMLElement>) {
    // tslint:disable-next-line
    this._numberOfTickets = (event.target as any).value;
}
```

What is the correct type for `event` that would allow me to remove the `as any` cast?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>`:

```
setNumberOfTickets(event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) {

    // Assuming `this._numberOfTickets` is a string. If not you have to parse it as a number
    this._numberOfTickets = event.target.value; 
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Really appreciate it ❤️